# Jenkins Pipeline CPS global lib resource file for shell script purpose

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a shell script that is common for many projects in side Jenkins, is it correct to put it into the resources folder and load it as below:

```
def script = libraryResource 'build/package_indexes/build_push.sh'
```

while this works:

```
sh script
```

but once I start making the `build_push.sh` script to accept arguments, it won't work since `script` is not a file...

Second question is that is it correct to output that `script` variable into a temp file such as

```
writeFile script '/tmp/tmp.sh'
sh "/tmp/tmp.sh 'cmd_arg'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash -c` will do the trick. just remember that the first param is $0 and not $1

for example:

my script -

```
 echo hello $0!
```

in Jenkinsfile

```
 def script = libraryResource 'hello.sh'
 sh "bash -c '$script' world"
```

and the result is hello world!