# Jenkins pipeline bubble up the shell exit code to fail the stage

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Absolute Jenkins pipeline/groovy noob here, I have a stage

```
stage('Building and Deploying'){
    def build = new Build()
    build.deploy()
}
```

which is using the shared lib, the source of the `Build.groovy` is here:

```
def deploy(branch='master', repo='xxx'){
    if (env.BRANCH_NAME.trim() == branch) {
        def script = libraryResource 'build/package_indexes/python/build_push.sh'
        // TODO: Test out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965725/jenkins-pipeline-cps-global-lib-resource-file-for-shell-script-purpose/40994132#40994132
        env.PYPI_REPO = repo
        sh script
    }else {
        echo "Not pushing to repo because branch is: "+env.BRANCH_NAME.trim()+" and not "+branch
    }
}
```

Problem is when failing to push the build to a remote repo (see below), the stage still ends up showing successful.

```
running upload
Submitting dist/xxx-0.0.7.tar.gz to https://xxx.jfrog.io/xxx/api/pypi/grabone-pypi-local
Upload failed (403): Forbidden
...
Finished: SUCCESS
```

How do I bubble up the exit code of the shell script and fail the stage?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The `sh` step returns the same status code that your actual sh command (your script in this case) returns. From [sh documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script) :

> Normally, a script which exits with a nonzero status code will cause the step to fail with an exception.

You have to make sure that your script returns a nonzero status code when it fails. If you're not sure what your script returns, you can check the return value using the `returnStatus` param of the `sh` step, which will not fail the build but will return the status code. E.g:

```
def statusCode = sh script:script, returnStatus:true
```

You can then use this status code to set the result of your current build.

You can use :

- `currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'` or `currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'` to mark the step as red/yellow respectively. In this case the build will still process the next steps.
- `error "Your error message"` if you want the build to fail and exit immediately.

Comment: cool thanks, I am having a different problem now can you please have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475073/jenkins-pipeline-sh-step-not-returning-different-status-code

Comment: is there a way to check the return status and run another command? come kind of if else