# Jenkins pipeline sh step not returning different status code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following code inside the pipeline

```
def deploy(branch='master', repo='xxx'){
    if (env.BRANCH_NAME.trim() == branch) {
        def script = libraryResource 'build/package_indexes/python/build_push.sh'
        env.PYPI_REPO = repo
        sh script
    }else {
        echo "Not pushing to repo because branch is: "+env.BRANCH_NAME.trim()+" and not "+branch
    }
}
```

And the script looks like this:

```
if [ -f "setup.cfg" ]; then
  # only build a wheel if setup.cfg exists, so we can disable wheel build if need be
  echo "Build package ${PACKAGE_NAME} tar.gz and wheel, and push to jfrog repo: $PYPI_REPO"
  python setup.py sdist upload -r jfrog
  echo "status code: $?"
fi
```

When I execute the script directly in shell:

`sh push.sh`

It returns the status code 1 when failed to push to the repo, see output:

```
Submitting dist/xxx-xxxx-0.0.7.tar.gz to https://xxx.jfrog.io/xxx/xxx-pypi/
Upload failed (405): Method Not Allowed
error: Upload failed (405): Method Not Allowed
status code: 1
```

But when I execute the pipeline in Jenkins, the status code is 0 when failed to push to the repo:

```
Submitting dist/xxx-xxxx-0.0.7.tar.gz to https://xxx.jfrog.io/xxx/xxx-pypi/
Upload failed (403): Forbidden
+ echo status code: 0
status code: 0
```

How do I make it to return status code 1 when it fails in Jenkins job?

**UPDATE**

Looks like the problem is not inside Jenkins, I can replicate the same problem on the shell of the Jenkins server.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a Jenkins pipeline issue but a bash issue. You can read this article to learn [how bash scripts exit codes work](http://bencane.com/2014/09/02/understanding-exit-codes-and-how-to-use-them-in-bash-scripts/).

> In Linux any script run from the command line has an exit code. With
>   Bash scripts, if the exit code is not specified in the script itself
>   the exit code used will be the exit code of the last command run.

Basically, your inner Python script returns a non-zero code but the echo command, which is the last command executed, is successful, making your script return a 0/success code.

You can either remove the `echo` or add an `exit 1` when needed.

Answer (score 1):

To return the status code, you need to invoke `sh` like this: `sh returnStatus: true, script: 'echo "test"'`

Regarding to your output, it looks like you have different results here, are you sure that you should get the same exit code? The `echo` is only invoked in the second case.