# Handling Jenkins Groovy script exceptions

Tags: c#, jenkins, groovy

I am executing a C# exe, CRS.exe, that I expect to return a non-zero value, such as -1.  I am using ps to get the value back, and have this within a stage:

```
  try{            
      pcode = (powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 'return Invoke-Expression -Command \" .\\perfmon\\CRS.exe hello \"'))''
      echo "Pcode =  ${pcode} "
      }
  catch (err) {echo err.message }
  echo "Pcode =  ${pcode} "
```

Based on this post, "Normally, a script which exits with a nonzero status code will cause the step to fail with an exception." --
[Jenkins pipeline bubble up the shell exit code to fail the stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428871/jenkins-pipeline-bubble-up-the-shell-exit-code-to-fail-the-stage)
I want to handle this non-zero result, is the exception handler the only way?
Results of above run:

```
    Running PowerShell script
tester arg = hello    
[Pipeline] echo
script returned exit code -1
[Pipeline] echo
Pcode =  null
```

Interestingly enough, a char return seems to be fine?  This returns without throwing an exception

```
 icode = (powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 'return Invoke-Expression -Command \'.\\perfmon\\zipInstaller.ps1 -urlString ' + fileContents + "'"))
                echo "icode =  ${icode} "

Results in 
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] powershell
[Chris] Running PowerShell script
[Pipeline] echo
icode =  -5
```

I would like to catch the return codes from the exe's and manage my groovy pipelines flow based on that.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A non-zero exit code is probably causing the command to fail before writing to the `pcode` variable. If you want to test this, try assigning a default value to pcode before the powershell call. If it's null, something is wrong with your command. If it's the default value, your command is failing before writing the variable.

Comment: Also, I assume the `''` on the end of the command is a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `returnStdout: true`, try using `returnStatus: true`. It should always return the exit code. Not as helpful if you need the output from the powershell command all at once (without `returnStdout`, it will just print output to the Jenkins log), but as a workaround for that you could pipe output to a file and then print that out.

Another option (but it's ugly, so I don't recommend it) is to call Powershell from a `bat` command. `bat` should mask the error code for the powershell command, so Jenkins won't get excited and fail automatically, and you'll still get stdout. Obviously not too helpful if you actually wanted the error code though. Your line would look something like

```
pcode = (bat(returnStdout: true, script: 'Powershell.exe "return Invoke-Expression -Command \" .\\perfmon\\CRS.exe hello \"'"))
```

That line will need a bit of refining, but it might be another option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that just might be the best way to go.  I was trying to be greedy and get it all in one shot, spoiled from the ps that doesn't throw.

Comment: @Chris I've edited the answer with another option that might work. It's ugly though.